# Magento 2.4.5 Checkout Error - Current Customer Does Not Have An Active Cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, version-upgrade

I am upgraded the Magento 2 from 2.4.3-p3 to 2.4.5.

Steps followed In Local Instance:

1. Install the fresh Magento 2.4.5 Version
2. Installed the custom implemented module (Disabled some module which faced the issue)
3. Installed all the 3-rd party modules (Disabled some module which faced issue)
4. Installed the 3-rd party theme (Disabled some views which faced issue)
5. Create a category
6. Added a product
7. Checkout completed successfully for the registered customer.

Steps followed In Staging Server:

1. Updated the Composer.json to upgrade Magento 2.4.5
2. Disabled the module which i disabled in my local instance
3. Disabled the theme which i disabled in my local instance

But still getting the "Current Customer Does Not Have An Active Cart" on staging server.

Need your input/idea suggestion to fix the issue

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue (2.4.5-p1) and in our case there were additional error messages of amqp in the log. Re-running the below commands and clearing the cache fixed the connection and the shopping cart issue.

```
setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

- Cache clear + flush
- Redis Cache Flush

Comment: In my case, just setup:upgrade solved the issue